# SQL 2000 Table Name as variable in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, dynamic-sql, tablename

Table Name :
RM_master

Fields :
cust_no
acct_no
acct_code

Question is, I want to make the table RM_master as a variable in the parameters in the stored procedure?

This has no syntax error but when I execute this in the query analyzer by right clicking on the stored procedure name the variable table name (RM_master) is not identified
Here is my stored procedure ;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RMQUERY

  @cusnumber  nvarchar (255) = '' ,
  @acctnumber nvarchar (255) = '' ,
  @master nvarchar (255) = ''

AS

BEGIN

SET @CUSNUMBER = @CUSNUMBER
DECLARE @RMRM AS NVARCHAR (255)
SET @RMRM =n'SELECT * FROM' + @MASTER + 'WHERE ACCT_NO =' + @ACCTNUMBER

EXEC RMQUERY2 
END
```

Comment: Can someone format the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended, as you simply are creating dynamic sql inside a stored proc. This opens up sql injection backdoors as you have no overview about what sql is created by the input: parameter values should never be used as query elements themselves, but only as values in a query (which can be dynamically created, though always should use parameters).

Though if you must, you should use the external stored proc sp_executesql and feed the sql to that proc.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning a value to @master.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add Spaces before and after the table name otherwise it will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROMTABLENAMEWHERE ACCT_NO =0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a space between "FROM" and "WHERE" in your dynamic sql query

Instead of

```
SET @RMRM =n'SELECT * FROM' + @MASTER + 'WHERE ACCT_NO =' + @ACCTNUMBER
```

You should do

```
SET @RMRM = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @MASTER + N' WHERE ACCT_NO =' + @ACCTNUMBER
```