# Retrieve data from all database with same table schema

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have created `ASP.NET C#` Web Application (with Database as `SQL Server 2008`). My Application Connects to Different databases (Say Count is 10). they all are have same structures i.e. Same Table Name,Stored Procedure Name,SP Argument Count & Type,Table Schema all are same.

**But data inside is different.**

I have stored procedure inside every database `dbo.usp_getData1` which accepts **some parameters** do some table scans and retrieve data with respect to only that database.

My Question is **How Can i Retrieve Data from all my Database** using only one of the stored Procedure (As Parameters/Table Structure is same) ?

I can achieve same either by `SQL Server` or `C# Coding`.

Views will be helpful for me ?

```
CREATE VIEW [ schema_name . ] view_name [ (column [ ,...n ] ) ] 
[ WITH <view_attribute> [ ,...n ] ] 
AS select_statement 
[ WITH CHECK OPTION ] [ ; ]

<view_attribute> ::= 
{
    [ ENCRYPTION ]
    [ SCHEMABINDING ]
    [ VIEW_METADATA ]     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select from multiple databases (on the same server) if you fully qualify the table name like Database.Schema.Table.

See e.g. 
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/selecting-data-from-different-databases

If you want to pass the database names as a parameter to your stored procedure, you'll probably have to resort to dynamic SQL, although this could potentially open a whole new can of worms.

See e.g. 
[SQL 2000 Table Name as variable in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650465/sql-2000-table-name-as-variable-in-stored-procedure) and 
http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Simple example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectEverything
    @tableName NVARCHAR(250)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName;
    EXEC(@sql);
END
GO
```

If you execute this proc:

```
EXEC dbo.SelectEverything 'SomeOtherDatabase.dbo.SomeTable'
```

It will select everything of table SomeTable in schema dbo of database SomeOtherDatabase.

But please read the link about dynamic SQL.

Comment: So Can i Pass Database Name as Parameter to my SP And my SP Will return Data from Only That Database ?

Comment: Also How Can i Pass Multiple Database Name in my SP and my SP will combine the resultset into one ?

Comment: Yes. I added a simple example to my original answer.

Comment: I have More than 10 Tables inside SP. Can i Pass Database Name Instead. And Write in SP Like `Use <DataBaseName> My SP Code` for All Database Name i Passed ?

Comment: To add multiple table or database names, see e.g. here http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114504/is-it-possible-to-send-a-collection-of-ids-as-a-ado-net-sql-parameter To iterate over multiple values, follow the example in the links above or maybe use a [CURSOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx). Use [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) to combine results from multiple selects.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [linq to sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/bb386976.aspx) and generate a [dbml file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399400.aspx).

And then you can acces every database with adjusting the connectionstring when initializing the datacontext:

```
MyDataContext firstDB = new MyDataContext(someConnectionstring);
MyDataContext secondDB = new MyDataContext(someOtherConnectionstring);
```